# Does eclipseProject task automatically add checkstyleNature to project?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, checkstyle

I have Checkstyle plugin configured inside Eclipse.

When I import some projects as "Existing Gradle Projects", checkstyle doesn't activate on them automatically.

I have to right click on each project and do "Activate Checkstyle here".

From a very old 2010 post, I found that we can configure eclipseProject task to add checkstyleNature in .project file like :slight_smile:

```
 eclipseProject {
  natures 'net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleNature'
  buildCommand 'net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleBuilder'
 }
```

Do we still need to do this? Or does Buildship takes care of it automatically ? If so, then why is it not working for me? Am I missing some obvious step ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this worked. So apparently BuildShip does not do it automatically yet.

```
eclipse {
    project {
          natures 'net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleNature'
          buildCommand 'net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleBuilder'
    }
}
```